# MPMoviePlayerController supported formats in iPad

Tags: video, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

According to the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController) reference:

> This class plays any movie or audio
>   file supported in iOS. This includes
>   both streamed content and fixed-length
>   files. For movie files, this typically
>   means files with the extensions .mov,
>   .mp4, .mpv, and .3gp and using one of
>   the following compression standards:
>
> - H.264 Baseline Profile Level 3.0
>     video, up to 640 x 480 at 30 fps. (The
>     Baseline profile does not support B
>     frames.)
> - MPEG-4 Part 2 video (Simple
>     Profile)

Does this mean that the highest video resolution that I can programatically play in an iPad is just 640x480? Or are the supported video formats for iPad specified somewhere else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Although it does say "up to 640x480" this isn't true. I'm playing 1280x720 resolution videos in an app at the moment and they are working just fine.

For some reason the class reference doesn't give an exhaustive list of formats/extensions supported. As jeeva said above it's probably best to use mp4/m4v if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Another list of supported media formats may be found in ["iOS Technology Overview"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH9-SW4), sections "Audio Technologies" and "Video Technologies".

Answer (score 0):

Technical Note TN2224 ([Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html)) includes in its list of encoding settings the recommended pixel dimensions and compatibility with various devices. It currently lists a maximum of 1280x720 at 2540 Mbps and compatibility with the iPad 1 and 2. Note thath the limitation on the pixel dimensions in the document is more a matter of data rate than device compatibility.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @harst: my edit is an example of what should be done when the answer is elsewhere: extract & summarize. The link Lix provides covers why.